# Upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10: “No new release found”

Tags: upgrade, 13.04, 13.10

I am trying to upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10 following the instructions given in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SaucyUpgrades:

1)

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
```

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
update-manager-core is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

2)

```
do-release-upgrade
```

Output:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

Many people have similar problems with upgrades for other versions. The most mentioned solutions I found are 1) to change from
Prompt=lts  to Prompt=Normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
and 2) to do the release upgrade as a normal user instead of root user. Non of these worked for me.

Any idea to solve my problem?

Thank you.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

13.04 reached the end of its life January 27 2014
13.10 reached the end of its life July 17 2014

You need a new install.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: By new install you mean skip versions instead of going one by one until I reach the one I want ?

Comment: Yes, skip versions. Install anew and fresh.

Comment: But then I might loose all I have in my computer right? Copying everything somewhere else would a pain in the ...

Comment: Yes, skip versions. Look out for LTS versions  (Long Term Support) which last longer that normal releases. 14.04 LTS was one. Nearly here is 16.04 LTS

Comment: You need to copy you stuff off the computer to an external hard drive. Do a new install and then replace the stuff.